# using boost::lambda_ to compress whitespaces in a string

Tags: c++, stl, boost-lambda

I am using boost::lambda to remove subsequent whitespaces in a string, leaving only one space. I tried this program.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>


int main()
{
    std::string s = "str     str st   st sss";
    //s.erase( std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), (boost::lambda::_1 == ' ') && (boost::lambda::_2== ' ')), s.end()); ///< works
    s.erase( std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), (boost::lambda::_1 == boost::lambda::_2== ' ')), s.end()); ///< does not work
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the commented line works fine, but the uncommented one does not.

How is

```
(boost::lambda::_1 == boost::lambda::_2== ' ')
```

different from

```
(boost::lambda::_1 == ' ') && (boost::lambda::_2== ' '))
```

in the above progam. The commented one also gives me a warning that "warning C4805: '==' : unsafe mix of type 'bool' and type 'const char' in operation"

Thanks.

Comment: What about boost::regex? Replace `/(\s)+/$1`? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and C++
a == b == x is very different than (a == x) && (b == x),
the former is interpreted as (a == b) == x,
which compares a with b and the result of that comparison (true or false)
is compared with x. In your case x is a space character,
and in typical implementation that uses ASCII its code is equal to 32,
comparing it with boolean value which is converted either to 0 or 1
gives always false.